# How to use dynamically loaded extensions on cross-compiled PHP?

Tags: php, arm

I have compiled PHP for the ARM platform.  I'm now trying to dynamically load an extension I've compiled for ARM via PHP.ini (extension=...).  However, the extension is not loaded and no errors are reported.

Things I've checked:

- PHP is reading in the correct PHP.ini file
- I can see changes made to the PHP.ini file with the -i option
- -d "extension=...", no extension loaded, no error.
- enable_dl=1, dl(...) from command line doesn't work ("dynamic modules are not supported in command line code")

PHP was compiled with the following options:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --target=arm -prefix=/php-5.5.8/_install --with-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite --without-pear --disable-mbregex --enable-sockets --enable-fpm --enable-json --enable-session --enable-filter --disable-opcache --disable-libxml --disable-simplexml --without-zlib --disable-all
```

Does this have something to do with the --disable-all option?  Is there something I have to do to enable dynamic extensions (even with enable_dl, I can't run dl(...) from command line)?  Do I have to statically compile my extension into PHP?

EDIT: Statically linking extension works fine.  It's not a problem with the extension.  But it would be much more ideal to be able to dynamically load extension.

Answer (score 2):

The extension's support seams to be disabled by the configure script when you try cross-compile PHP.

You could check on the cross-compiled CLI

```
:~>php -i |grep Dynamic
Dynamic Library support not available<br />.
```

If you would like to use extension you have 2 ways:
 - hack the configure script to manualy enable to extension's support, bypassing the checks
 - use a native compiler for the target system

I used the second one, successfully loading extensions on Arm with a native-compiled PHP 5.3.28

Native complied CLI

```
:~>php -i |grep Dynamic
Dynamic Library Support => enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem when cross compiling to mips for the freetz php package and
finally found a [busybox Patch](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2015-April/124564.html)

Their solution was to

1. patch /ext/opcache/config.m4 autoconf macros
2. Add some shm related compiler flags to their makefile

In addition, i also commenced out line 3968 within 
php-5.6.40/aclocal.m4:

- `# https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49314 if test
  "$cross_compiling" = yes; then :   [$4]`
- Also compiled php-cgi statically using -all-static

...which solved the problem -after a lengthy search.
Hope that might help others by posting here.
cheers, Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bug report related to this issue:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60109

Following the workaround seems to fix the issue:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -DHAVE_LIBDL"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -ldl"
```